# Добавить в архив только директории с определенным именем

Tags: linux, tar, archive

Есть дерево директорий вида:

```
.
└── files
    ├── dir1
    │   ├── test
    │   ├── xxx
    │   └── yyy
    └── dir2
        ├── test
        └── zzz
```

Задача сделать архив всех файлов, но только в директориях с именем test, сохранив структуру папок. Другими словами исключить папки xxx, yyy, zzz из примера выше.

Как получить такой архив через tar в Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

исключить каталоги `xxx`, `yyy` и `zzz` можно с помощью опции `--exclude=шаблон`:

```
$ tar -cf файл.tar --exclude=xxx --exclude=yyy --exclude=zzz files
```

---

а можно пойти противоположным путём.

если требуются только файлы из каталогов, в пути к которым встречается слово *test*, то такой командой их можно найти:

```
$ find files/ -type f -path \*test\*
```

и, воспользовавшись программой `xargs`, внести в архив:

```
$ find files/ -type f -path \*test\* | xargs tar -cf файл.tar
```

---

если в именах файлов/каталогов могут встретиться спец-символы (например, пробелы), то надо дополнить вызов `find` опцией `-print0`, а `xargs` — опцией `-0`:

```
$ find files/ -type f -path \*test\* -print0 | xargs -0 tar -cf файл.tar
```

---

если есть подозрение, что количество файлов, помноженное на длину пути к ним, может превысить максимальную длину команды (узнать, что известно по поводу лимитов программе `xargs`, можно командой `:|xargs --show-limits`), то имеет смысл заменить у программы `tar` опцию `-c` (создание архива) на опцию `-r` (добавление файлов в архив):

```
$ find files/ -type f -path \*test\* -print0 | xargs -0 tar -rf файл.tar
```

---

пример вывода запроса «про лимиты»:

```
$ :|xargs --show-limits
Your environment variables take up 2510 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2092594
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2090084
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
```

четвёртая строка — как раз про максимальную длину команды.

Comment: Если find найдет очень много файлов, то xargs вызовет tar несколько раз и мы получим архив только из последней "пачки".

Comment: @avp, справедливое замечание. опцию `-c` можно заменить на `-r`.

Comment: В том-то и опасность таких конструкций, что они завершаются с ошибкой **очень редко** (и как раз, когда никто такой подлянки не ждет) / А не стоит перед `tar  -r` на всякий случай архив удалять?